# Does Flutter import things more than once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app in Flutter. I'm wondering if importing the same thing across many files has a negative effect on performance. For example:

Files *a.dart*, *b.dart*, and *c.dart* use `import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';`

Should I instead create a new file *z.dart* which uses this import and contains all the functions my program needs from this import? With this new file, I would have the others use functions from *z.dart* so the import only gets called once. Does this help or does it make a difference if they all import the same thing?

Comment: `import`s are a compile-time notion.  They should not affect runtime performance. I would not expect `import`ing the same library multiple times (as opposed to once) to have an effect on compilation time.  However, `import`ing a library you don't need at all could negatively compilation time, hot reload times, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no (kind of). When Dart code is compiled, it goes through a process called "tree-shaking". This basically means that all unnecessary code is removed from the final build.

This means that the final build will only have one instance of the import, no matter how many of your files call for that import. The final build size will not be affected. The only negative effect might be a few nano-seconds slower compile time.

Because the negative effects are negligible (if they exist at all), your decision on importing on a file-by-file basis vs a common import file should be based on what makes your code maintainable and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.
Flutter only import file once, only when the file executed like this

```
new Home() <- all import inside home class will be executed once
```